# How to configure razorpages to not use Index.cshtml as the default page in folders under the Pages folder

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages, .net-7.0

To avoid having many files named Index.cshtml in my codebase, I want to use filenames named after the subfolder and with the suffix "Page" as the default pages in a Razor pages site instead of the conventional Index.cshtml.

So instead of having this file structure

```
/Pages
  /Settings
    Index.cshtml
  /Users
    Index.cshtml
```

I want this file structure:

```
/Pages
  /Settings
    SettingsPage.cshtml
  /Users
    UsersPage.cshtml
```

I have tried setting the route in SettingsPage.cshtml like this:

```
@page "/"
```

But this results in this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

/Index
/Settings/SettingsPage
```

How can I configure the razorpages options/conventions to use what I described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution I found was to simply use the folder name in the @page directive like this:

Instead of having this file `/Pages/Settings/Index.cshtml`
where the first line is

```
@page
```

I have this file `/Pages/Settings/SettingsPage.cshtml`
where the first line is:

```
@page "/Settings"
```

And when linking to the page I need to specify the new page file name instead of Index, for instance, ie. instead of:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Settings/Index">Settings</a>
```

I use

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Settings/SettingsPage">Settings</a>
```

This works it seems. Any comments or suggestions are still much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates there're Mutipule razor pages (Pages/Index.cshtml&Pages/Settings/SettingsPage.cshtml)share the same route.

If you want Pages/Settings/SettingsPage.cshtml match the path "/",Set Pages/Index.cshtml with another route

For example `@page "/Index"`

If you didn't modify anything, /Pages/Index.cshtml would match the path"/" and "/Index" You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages)  ，When you specific the path"/" for Pages/Settings/SettingsPage.cshtml, the error occurs

Answer (score -1):

Try to set your SettingsPage.cshtml as below:

```
@page "/SettingsPage"
```

result:
[image]